# Python - how to write this in vector form

Tags: python, vectorization

```
def compute(c, r):
    s = 0;
    l = len(c);
    for i in range(l):
        s = s + c[i]*f(r[i]);
    return s
```

Comment: What do you mean by "vector form"?

Comment: try to explain your question for a good answer.

Comment: You do not need to end statements with `;`, in Python.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know what you mean by vector form (unless you are using numpy?), but I would write your function like this:

```
def compute(c, r):
  return sum(x*f(y) for x,y in zip(c,r))
```

If you are using numpy you can use whole-array expressions instead of generator expressions, but in that case `c` and  `r` must be numpy arrays:

```
def compute(c, r):
  return (c*f(r)).sum()
```

Comment: … or `(c*f(r)).sum()`, with NumPy.